# SQL Server 2008 can't login with newly created user using a script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a user in `SQL-2008 R2` using the following script

```
Use [CamelotShiftManagement]
CREATE LOGIN [CamelotShiftManagementUser] 
WITH PASSWORD=N'123', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[CamelotShiftManagement], 
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

When I try to log-in using that user i get the following error

TITLE: Connect to Server

---

> Cannot connect to localhost.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'CamelotShiftManagementUser'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=4064&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this before that:

```
ALTER LOGIN [CamelotShiftManagementUser] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = master
```

Comment: Sorry i did not quite understood.. before what script i should run this .. it will chage the default DB of my user to use master .. bu the user is not created before my script.. can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Means run this script..OR Select default database as `master` from the `options >>` button. @Mortalus

Comment: Okay I did .. it worked.. can you explain why cant i use my new database as the default DB for the new login ?

Comment: It means, The user `CamelotShiftManagementUser` does not have access to its `default database`...so you will see `Blank default database` will not be able to login to the instance. so it’s a good practice to point a `default` database to some system database. that is `master`  @Mortalus

Comment: Thank you.. to fix that i have added another script that will grant db_owner role for the newly created login and that worked.. i did not realized that this was the problem .. thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the login's default database. With sqlcmd, you can do the following:

```
sqlcmd -d master -U sa -P mypassword
and then:
alter login sa with default_database = master
```